# I want to plot a shanky plot for 254 unique names that belong to different years of a paricular microbe in R

Tags: r

[enter image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EaSS.png) here I want to plot a shanky plot for 254 unique names that belong to different years of a particular from 1 species in R. as the no. is high is getting very clumsy

i ran this code

```
nodes <- data.frame(name=c(as.character(links$source),as.character(links$target)) %>% unique())

links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name)-1

links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name)-1

sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",Value = "value", NodeID = "name",sinksRight=FALSE, fontSize = 10, nodeWidth = 5, nodePadding = 5)
```

and got that attached diagram

i need a diag of the shanky for 254 names from different year retrieved from 1 species i an clear way
can we tilt the daig and bring down all the names so that it gets space.